# Tested code in Seattle is giving an Access Violation in Alexandria

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have used `Cromis.DirectoryWatch.pas` successfully in Delphi 10 Seattle for years, both 32-bit & 64-bit. And even in Delphi 11.3 Alexandria in 32-bit, it's fine.

But, in 64-bit, it gives an Access Violation when a renamed folder is captured.

I tried downloading the lastest Cromis files (https://github.com/CPsoftBE/BackupOfCromis), but the same issue happens.

Line 253:

```pascal
PWord(Cardinal(NotifyRecord.AMsg) + NotifyData^.FileNameLength)^ := 0;
```

> Access violation at address 0000000000F6E5C8 in module 'ABCD64BIT.exe'. Write of address 00000000B0D61FDA

```pascal
(*
 * This software is distributed under BSD license.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Iztok Kacin, Cromis (iztok.kacin@gmail.com).
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
 *   list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this
 *   list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or
 *   other materials provided with the distribution.
 * - Neither the name of the Iztok Kacin nor the names of its contributors may be
 *   used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific
 *   prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.
 * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
 * BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE
 * OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * NOTICE OF CODE ORIGIN
 *
 * This code was derived from the original code of author "Gleb Yourchenko"
 * The original code "FnugryDirWatch" can still be found at Torry Components
 * The URL is: http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=252
 *
 * The code was taken as a starting point and then mainly written from scratch
 * keeping some of the healthy code parts. So I am not in any way an author of
 * the original idea. But I am the author of all the changes and new code parts.
 *
 * ============================================================================
)

unit Cromis.DirectoryWatch;

interface

uses
   Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Messages, SyncObjs, DateUtils;

const
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME   = $00000001;
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME    = $00000002;
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES  = $00000004;
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE        = $00000008;
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE  = $00000010;
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS = $00000020;
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION    = $00000040;
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY    = $00000100;

const
  cShutdownTimeout = 3000;
  cFileWaitTimeout = 0;
  
type
  // the filters that control when the watch is triggered
  TWatchOption = (woFileName, woDirName, woAttributes, woSize, woLastWrite,
                  woLastAccess, woCreation, woSecurity);
  TWatchOptions = set of TWatchOption;

  // the actions that are the result of the watch being triggered
  TWatchAction = (waAdded, waRemoved, waModified, waRenamedOld, waRenamedNew);
  TWatchActions = set of TWatchAction;

  TFileChangeNotifyEvent = procedure(const Sender: TObject;
                                     const Action: TWatchAction;
                                     const FileName: string
                                     ) of Object;
  TOnError = procedure(const Sender: TObject;
                       const ErrorCode: Integer;
                       const ErrorMessage: string
                       ) of Object;

  TDirectoryWatch = class
  private
    FWatchOptions : TWatchOptions;
    FWatchActions : TWatchActions;
    FWatchSubTree : Boolean;
    FWatchThread  : TThread;
    FBufferSize   : Integer;
    FWndHandle    : HWND;
    FDirectory    : string;
    FAbortEvent   : THandle;
    FOnError      : TOnError;
    FOnChange     : TNotifyEvent;
    FOnNotify     : TFileChangeNotifyEvent;
    procedure WatchWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
    procedure SetDirectory(const Value: string);
    procedure SetWatchOptions(const Value: TWatchOptions);
    procedure SetWatchActions(const Value: TWatchActions);
    procedure SetWatchSubTree(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure DeallocateHWnd(Wnd: HWND);
    function MakeFilter: Integer;
  protected
    procedure Change; virtual;
    procedure AllocWatchThread;
    procedure ReleaseWatchThread;
    procedure RestartWatchThread;
    procedure Notify(const Action: Integer;
                     const FileName: string
                     ); virtual;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Start;
    procedure Stop;
    function Running: Boolean;
    property WatchSubTree: Boolean read FWatchSubTree write SetWatchSubTree;
    property WatchOptions: TWatchOptions read FWatchOptions write SetWatchOptions;
    property WatchActions: TWatchActions read FWatchActions write SetWatchActions;
    property BufferSize: Integer read FBufferSize write FBufferSize;
    property Directory: string read FDirectory write SetDirectory;
    // notification properties. Notify about internal and exernal changes
    property OnNotify: TFileChangeNotifyEvent read FOnNotify write FOnNotify;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
    property OnError: TOnError read FOnError write FOnError;
  end;

  // waits for the file to be ready (it is not in use anymore) or timeout occurs
  procedure WaitForFileReady(const FileName: string; const Timeout: Cardinal = cFileWaitTimeout);

implementation

type
  PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION = ^TFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION;
  TFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION = record
    NextEntryOffset : Cardinal;
    Action          : Cardinal;
    FileNameLength  : Cardinal;
    FileName        : array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of WideChar;
  end;

const
  WM_DIRWATCH_ERROR    = WM_USER + 137;
  WM_DIRWATCH_NOTIFY   = WM_USER + 138;

  FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY  = $0001;

const
  // error messages
  cErrorInWatchThread = 'Error "%s" in watch thread. Error code: %d';
  cErrorCreateWatchError = 'Error trying to create file handle for "%s". Error code: %d';

type
  TDirWatchThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FWatchSubTree : Boolean;
    FAbortEvent   : THandle;
    FChangeEvent  : THandle;
    FBufferSize   : Integer;
    FWndHandle    : HWND;
    FDirHandle    : THandle;
    FDirectory    : string;
    FIOResult     : Pointer;
    FFilter       : Integer;
    procedure SignalError(const ErrorMessage: string; ErrorCode: Cardinal = 0);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const Directory: string;
                       const WndHandle: HWND;
                       const BufferSize: Integer;
                       const AbortEvent: THandle;
                       const TypeFilter: Cardinal;
                       const aWatchSubTree: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

procedure WaitForFileReady(const FileName: string; const Timeout: Cardinal);
var
  hFile: THandle;
  StartTime: TDateTime;
begin
  StartTime := Now;

  // wait to close
  while (MilliSecondsBetween(Now, StartTime) < Timeout) or (Timeout = 0) do
  begin
    hFile := CreateFile(PChar(FileName), GENERIC_READ, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    if hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    begin
      CloseHandle(hFile);
      Break;
    end;

    // wait for file
    Sleep(50);
  end;
end;

procedure TDirWatchThread.Execute;
var
  NotifyData: PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION;
  Events: array [0..1] of THandle;
  ErrorMessage: string;
  WaitResult: DWORD;
  NextEntry: Cardinal;
  FileName: PWideChar;
  Overlap: TOverlapped;
  ResSize: Cardinal;
begin
  FillChar(Overlap, SizeOf(TOverlapped), 0);
  Overlap.hEvent := FChangeEvent;

  // set the array of events
  Events[0] := FChangeEvent;
  Events[1] := FAbortEvent;

  while not Terminated do
  try
    if ReadDirectoryChangesW(FDirHandle, FIOResult, FBufferSize, FWatchSubtree, FFilter, @ResSize, @Overlap, nil) then
    begin
      WaitResult := WaitForMultipleObjects(Length(Events), @Events, FALSE, INFINITE);

      // check if we have terminated the thread
      if WaitResult <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
      begin
        Terminate;
        Exit;
      end;

      if WaitResult = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
      begin
        if GetOverlappedResult(FDirHandle, Overlap, ResSize, False) then
        begin
          NotifyData := FIOResult;

          // check overflow
          if ResSize = 0 then
          begin
            ErrorMessage := SysErrorMessage(ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR);
            SignalError(ErrorMessage, ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR);
          end;

          repeat
            NextEntry := NotifyData^.NextEntryOffset;

            // get memory for filename and fill it with data
            GetMem(FileName, NotifyData^.FileNameLength + SizeOf(WideChar));
            Move(NotifyData^.FileName, Pointer(FileName)^, NotifyData^.FileNameLength);
            
            //v Below line gives Access Violation in Alexandria 64Bit only, Works fine with Seattle 32Bit/64Bit also works fine with Alexandria 32Bit
            PWord(Cardinal(FileName) + NotifyData^.FileNameLength)^ := 0;

            // send the message about the filename information and advance to the next entry
            PostMessage(FWndHandle, WM_DIRWATCH_NOTIFY, NotifyData^.Action, LParam(FileName));
            PByte(NotifyData) := PByte(DWORD(NotifyData) + NextEntry);
          until (NextEntry = 0);
        end
        else
        begin
          ErrorMessage := SysErrorMessage(GetLastError);
          SignalError(ErrorMessage);
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      ErrorMessage := SysErrorMessage(GetLastError);
      SignalError(ErrorMessage);
    end;
  except
    on E :Exception do
    begin
      ErrorMessage := E.Message;
      SignalError(ErrorMessage);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TDirWatchThread.SignalError(const ErrorMessage: string; ErrorCode: Cardinal);
var
  ErrorMsg: PChar;
  MessageSize: Integer;
begin
  if ErrorCode = 0 then
    ErrorCode := GetLastError;

  // calculate the size of the error message buffer
  MessageSize := Length(ErrorMessage) * SizeOf(Char) + SizeOf(WideChar);

  GetMem(ErrorMsg, MessageSize);
  StrPCopy(ErrorMsg, ErrorMessage);
  PostMessage(FWndHandle, WM_DIRWATCH_ERROR, ErrorCode, LPARAM(ErrorMsg));
end;

constructor TDirWatchThread.Create(const Directory: string;
                                   const WndHandle: HWND;
                                   const BufferSize: Integer;
                                   const AbortEvent: THandle;
                                   const TypeFilter: Cardinal;
                                   const aWatchSubTree: Boolean);
begin
   //
   // Retrieve proc pointer, open directory to
   // watch and allocate buffer for notification data.
   // (note, it is done before calling inherited
   // create (that calls BeginThread) so any exception
   // will be still raised in caller's thread)
   //
   FDirHandle := CreateFile(PChar(Directory),
                            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                            FILE_SHARE_READ OR
                            FILE_SHARE_DELETE OR
                            FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                            nil, OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS OR
                            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                            0);

   if FDirHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
     raise Exception.CreateFmt(cErrorCreateWatchError, [Directory, GetLastError]);

   FChangeEvent := CreateEvent(nil, FALSE, FALSE, nil);
   FAbortEvent := AbortEvent;

   // allocate the buffer memory
   FBufferSize := BufferSize * SizeOf(TFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION);
   GetMem(FIOResult, FBufferSize);

   FWatchSubTree := aWatchSubtree;
   FWndHandle := WndHandle;
   FDirectory := Directory;
   FFilter := TypeFilter;

   inherited Create(False);
end;


destructor TDirWatchThread.Destroy;
begin
   CloseHandle(FChangeEvent);

   if FDirHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE  then
     CloseHandle(FDirHandle);
   if Assigned(FIOResult) then
     FreeMem(FIOResult);

   inherited Destroy;
end;

{ TFnugryDirWatch }

procedure TDirectoryWatch.AllocWatchThread;
begin
  if FWatchThread = nil then
  begin
    FAbortEvent := CreateEvent(nil, FALSE, FALSE, nil);
    FWatchThread := TDirWatchThread.Create(Directory,
                                           FWndHandle,
                                           FBufferSize,
                                           FAbortEvent,
                                           MakeFilter,
                                           WatchSubtree);
  end;
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.ReleaseWatchThread;
var
  AResult: Cardinal;
  ThreadHandle: THandle;
begin
  if FWatchThread <> nil then
  begin
    ThreadHandle := FWatchThread.Handle;
    // set and close event
    SetEvent(FAbortEvent);

    // wait and block until thread is finished
    AResult := WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle, cShutdownTimeout);

    // check if we timed out
    if AResult = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
      TerminateThread(ThreadHandle, 0);

    FreeAndNil(FWatchThread);
    CloseHandle(FAbortEvent);
  end;

end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.RestartWatchThread;
begin
  Stop;
  Start;
end;

function TDirectoryWatch.Running: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FWatchThread <> nil;
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.DeallocateHWnd(Wnd: HWND);
var
  Instance: Pointer;
begin
  Instance := Pointer(GetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_WNDPROC));

  if Instance <> @DefWindowProc then
  begin
    { make sure we restore the default
      windows procedure before freeing memory }
    SetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_WNDPROC, Longint(@DefWindowProc));
    FreeObjectInstance(Instance);
  end;

  DestroyWindow(Wnd);
end;

destructor TDirectoryWatch.Destroy;
begin
  Stop;
  DeallocateHWnd(FWndHandle);

  inherited Destroy;
end;

constructor TDirectoryWatch.Create;
begin
   FWndHandle := AllocateHWnd(WatchWndProc);
   FWatchSubtree := True;
   FBufferSize := 32;

   // construct the default watch actions and options
   FWatchActions := [waAdded, waRemoved, waModified, waRenamedOld, waRenamedNew];
   FWatchOptions := [woFileName, woDirName, woAttributes, woSize, woLastWrite,
                     woLastAccess, woCreation, woSecurity];

//   FWatchOptions := [woDirName]; //[ss]
end;



procedure TDirectoryWatch.SetWatchActions(const Value: TWatchActions);
begin
  if FWatchActions <> Value then
  begin
    FWatchActions := Value;

    if Running then
      RestartWatchThread;

    Change;
  end;
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.SetWatchOptions(const Value: TWatchOptions);
begin
  if FWatchOptions <> Value then
  begin
    FWatchOptions := Value;

    if Running then
      RestartWatchThread;

    Change;
  end;
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.WatchWndProc(var Msg :TMessage);
var
  ErrorCode: Cardinal;
  ErrorMessage: string;
begin
   case Msg.msg of
     WM_DIRWATCH_NOTIFY:
     //
     // Retrieve notify data and forward
     // the event to TDirectoryWatch's notify
     // handler. Free filename string (allocated
     // in WatchThread's notify handler.)
     //
     begin
        try
           Notify(Msg.wParam, WideCharToString(PWideChar(Msg.lParam)));
        finally
          if Msg.lParam <> 0 then
            FreeMem(Pointer(Msg.lParam));
        end;
     end;

     WM_DIRWATCH_ERROR:
     //
     // Disable dir watch and re-raise
     // exception on error
     //
     begin
        try
          ErrorMessage := StrPas(PChar(Msg.lParam));
          ErrorCode := Msg.WParam;

          if Assigned(FOnError) then
            FOnError(Self, ErrorCode, ErrorMessage);
        finally
          if Msg.lParam <> 0 then
            FreeMem(Pointer(Msg.lParam));
        end;
     end;
     //
     // pass all other messages down the line
     //
     else
     begin
       Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FWndHandle, Msg.Msg, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
       Exit;
     end;
   end;
end;

function TDirectoryWatch.MakeFilter: Integer;
const
  FilterFlags: array [TWatchOption] of Integer = (FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
                                                  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME,
                                                  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES,
                                                  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE,
                                                  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
                                                  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS,
                                                  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION,
                                                  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY);
var
  Flag: TWatchOption;
begin
  Result := 0;

  for Flag in FWatchOptions do
    Result := Result or FilterFlags[Flag];
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.SetWatchSubTree(const Value :Boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FWatchSubtree then
  begin
    FWatchSubtree := Value;

    if Running then
      RestartWatchThread;

    Change;
  end;
end;


procedure TDirectoryWatch.Start;
begin
  if FDirectory = '' then
    raise Exception.Create('Please specify a directory to watch');

  if not Running then
  begin
    AllocWatchThread;
    Change;
  end;
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.Stop;
begin
  if Running then
  begin
    ReleaseWatchThread;
    Change;
  end;
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.SetDirectory(const Value: string);
begin
  if StrIComp(PChar(Trim(Value)), PChar(FDirectory)) <> 0 then
  begin
    FDirectory := Trim(Value);

    if Running then
      RestartWatchThread;

    Change;
  end;
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.Change;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TDirectoryWatch.Notify(const Action: Integer; const FileName: string);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnNotify) then
    if TWatchAction(Action - 1) in FWatchActions then
      FOnNotify(Self, TWatchAction(Action - 1), FileName);
end;

end.
```

Comment: High-entropy 64-bit ASLR is enabled by default with 11.3. This means the high bits of 64 bit addresses are much less likely to be all zeros. This exposes bad code that uses 32bit math on pointers.

Comment: I other words your code has always been broken, but now you got lucky and the system is flushing out your bugs.

Answer (score 5):

Cardinal is 32 bits on all platforms so `Cardinal(NotifyRecord.AMsg)` is 32 bit pointer math which is wrong on 64 bit. It fails more reliably with high-entropy 64-bit ASLR enabled but has always been a bug.

On modern Delphi it is more common to drop the cast and enable pointer arithmetic. See: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)

Comment: Thanks, I got what you'll are saying but am clueless what I can do about it ?

Comment: @AllanFernandes The simplest change would be to cast to `NativeUInt ` instead of `Cardinal`. But a better solution is to get rid of the integral cast to begin with.

Comment: NativeUInt did the trick, thanks @RemyLebeau . Also Thanks for improving the language in the question, was an eye opener.